# How to use Instapy to unfollow users with less than a certain number of followers or having less than a certain follower to following ratio?

Tags: python

I have recently started using Instapy from https://github.com/timgrossmann/InstaPy to automate my Instagram. Presently I am using it to follow similar accounts, unfollow non-followers, liking and commenting. I read the documentation but could not find anything  that can help me unfollow users with less than a certain number of followers, or more than a certain follower-following ratio.

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

```
session.grab_followers(username="account_name", amount="full", live_match=True, store_locally=false)
```

gets a list of all followers from a username and you can just get the length of that and you could change followers to following as well for the ratio.
The documentation link is here: https://github.com/timgrossmann/InstaPy/blob/master/DOCUMENTATION.md#grab-followers-of-a-user

Answer (score 0):

Adding Answer to this Query. Although it 1-year delay, it might help someone else if they come up with same questions.

There is a function "get_relationship_counts" in Util.py Module that give the count of followers and Following of a user. you can use to build your function in Insta.py.